# How do I access the data filters in this MVC3 VB application BEFORE loading the data?

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a few filters for table data represented by dropdowns, but the table data is really huge and the process hangs for a few minutes until the complete table is rendered; only then is the table presented and I can use those filters.

I want to be able to access the filters before presenting the data; I don't want to wait for the table to load.  This could be done by separating the filters into another view/controller, but I want to handle inside the `index()` method.

I tried to delete the part where the process checks if filters are set, but then than it will work if I set all filters only.

Relevant code:

```
Function Index(SelectedTimeType As System.Nullable(Of Integer), SelectedTimeStatus As System.Nullable(Of Integer), SelectedProject As System.Nullable(Of Integer), SelectedTask As System.Nullable(Of Integer)) As ActionResult
        Dim tipovi = unitOfWork.TimeTypeRepository.Get(orderBy:=Function(q) q.OrderBy(Function(d) d.Opis))
        ViewBag.SelectedTimeType = New SelectList(tipovi, "TimeTypeID", "Opis", SelectedTimeType)
        Dim statusi = unitOfWork.TimeStatusRepository.Get(orderBy:=Function(q) q.OrderBy(Function(d) d.Opis))
        ViewBag.SelectedTimeStatus = New SelectList(statusi, "TimeStatusID", "Opis", SelectedTimeStatus)
        Dim projekti = unitOfWork.ProjectRepository.Get(orderBy:=Function(q) q.OrderBy(Function(d) d.Opis))
        ViewBag.SelectedProject = New SelectList(projekti, "ProjekatID", "Opis", SelectedProject)
        Dim taskovi = unitOfWork.TaskRepository.Get(orderBy:=Function(q) q.OrderBy(Function(d) d.Opis))
        ViewBag.SelectedTask = New SelectList(taskovi, "TaskID", "Opis", SelectedTask)

        Dim timeTypeID As Integer = SelectedTimeType.GetValueOrDefault()
        Dim timeStatusID As Integer = SelectedTimeStatus.GetValueOrDefault()
        Dim projekatID As Integer = SelectedProject.GetValueOrDefault()
        Dim taskID As Integer = SelectedTask.GetValueOrDefault()
        Return View(unitOfWork.TimeTrackingRepository.Get(
                    filter:=Function(d) Not (SelectedTimeType.HasValue And SelectedTimeStatus.HasValue And SelectedProject.HasValue And SelectedTask.HasValue) OrElse (d.TimeTypeID = timeTypeID And d.TimeStatusID = timeStatusID And d.ProjectID = projekatID And d.TaskID = taskID),
                    orderBy:=Function(q) q.OrderBy(Function(d) d.TimeTrackingID)))
    End Function
```